Invalid runtimeconfig.json .net 8 docker container using alpine linux on a Mac
I'm trying to create a docker container for a .NET8 API on a Mac to be deployed to CloudRun,
this works perfectly when using .NET6 as we already have some running in production for about a year.
But when I execute
docker build . -t testapi:alpine-secure-test-runtime  -f Dockerfile-TestAPI
I get the following error:
[build  7/10] RUN dotnet restore -v d "XYZ.Test.API/XYZ.Test.API.csproj":
0.114 A JSON parsing exception occurred in [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/dotnet.runtimeconfig.json], offset 0 (line 1, column 1): The document is empty.
0.114 Invalid runtimeconfig.json [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/dotnet.runtimeconfig.json] [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/dotnet.runtimeconfig.dev.json]
It seems that this is the path is expecting /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/
but this is where it is actually located  /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/
Based on that I ran the command grep -r '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303' on my Mac I get in return hundreds of matches from a docker file named **./.docker/scout/sbom/sha256/d42c4838eac81b78f129fac7d901a005615e9d4a0a5eb08d1898d442f36f2e6a/sbom.json **.
At this point I'm not sure if this is what is breaking the container creation process or how to fix it. I was expecting to find a configurable instance that would solve the problem once set up correctly.
Also tried using fixing the waring FromPlatformFlagConstDisallowed and accomplished it adding an ARG to store it before FROM. Unfortunately it still displays the same error.
I've visited Rider Community Forums, Docker Community Forums/Git and SO looking for clarification on my issue but unfortunately I have not found anything that points me in the right direction.
This process does not fail when using .Net6 or when using .NET8 auto generated project DockerFile, only fails when using alpine.
Please advise.
Development machine:
MacMini M1 16 GB
OS: Sonoma 14.5 (23F79)
.NET Version: 8.0.303
Docker Desktop Version:
Version: 4.33.0 (160616)
Engine: 27.1.1
Compose: v2.29.1-desktop.1
Credential Helper: v0.8.2
Kubernetes: v1.30.2
DockerFile:

`   FROM --platform=linux/amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:8.0-alpine AS base
    WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE 8080
    ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080


    #add ICU en-us (icu-libs) to Alpine and TimezoneInfo (tzdata)
    RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
    #only for languages that are not English
    #RUN apk add --no-cache icu-data-full 
    RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata

    RUN adduser -u 1111 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
    USER appuser

    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine  AS build
    ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY ["XYZ.Test.API/XYZ.Test.API.csproj", "XYZ.Test.API/"]
    COPY ["XYZ.Test.Common/XYZ.Test.Common.csproj", "XYZ.Test.Common/"]
    COPY ["XYZ.Test.Data/XYZ.Test.Data.csproj", "XYZ.Test.Data/"]
    COPY ["XYZ.Test.Domain/XYZ.Test.Domain.csproj", "XYZ.Test.Domain/"]
    RUN dotnet restore "XYZ.Test.API/XYZ.Test.API.csproj"
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR "/src/XYZ.Test.API"
    RUN dotnet build "XYZ.Test.API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build


    FROM build AS publish
    ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
    RUN dotnet publish "XYZ.Test.API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION  -o /app/publish \
        -r linux-musl-x64 \
        --self-contained true \
        -p:PublishTrimmed=true \
        -p:PublishSingleFile=true

        FROM base AS final
        WORKDIR /app
        COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
        ENTRYPOINT ["./XYZ.Test.API"]`

Docker Log:
    `(base) dev@dev-Mac-mini XYZ.Test % docker build . -t testapi:alpine-secure-test-runtime  -f   Dockerfile-TestAPI
    Building 0.2s (18/23) docker:desktop-linux
    [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-TestAPI  0.0s
    transferring dockerfile: 1.93kB 0.0s
    WARN: FromPlatformFlagConstDisallowed: FROM --platform flag should not use constant value   "linux/amd64" (line 2) 0.0s
    [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine 0.0s
    [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:8.0-alpine 0.0s
    [internal] load .dockerignore 0.0s
    transferring context: 417B 0.0s
    [build  1/10] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine 0.0s
    [internal] load build context 0.1s transferring context: 47.30kB 0.1s
    [base 1/5] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:8.0-alpine 0.0s
    CACHED [base 2/5] WORKDIR /app  0.0s
    CACHED [base 3/5] RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs 0.0s
    CACHED [base 4/5] RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata 0.0s
    CACHED [base 5/5] RUN adduser -u 8888 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R    appuser /app 0.0s
    CACHED [final 1/2] WORKDIR /app 0.0s
    CACHED [build  2/10] WORKDIR /src 0.0s
    CACHED [build  3/10] COPY [XYZ.Test.API/XYZ.Test.API.csproj, XYZ.Test.API/] 0.0s
    CACHED [build  4/10] COPY [XYZ.Test.Common/XYZ.Test.Common.csproj, XYZ.Test.Common/] 0.0s
    CACHED [build  5/10] COPY [XYZ.Test.Data/XYZ.Test.Data.csproj, XYZ.Test.Data/] 0.0s
    CACHED [build  6/10] COPY [XYZ.Test.Domain/XYZ.Test.Domain.csproj, XYZ.Test.Domain/] 0.0s
    ERROR [build  7/10] RUN dotnet restore -v d "XYZ.Test.API/XYZ.Forms.API.csproj" 0.1s
    **# [build  7/10] RUN dotnet restore -v d "XYZ.Test.API/XYZ.Test.API.csproj":
    0.114 A JSON parsing exception occurred   in[/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/dotnet.runtimeconfig.json], offset 0 (line 1, column 1): The   document is empty.
    0.114 Invalid runtimeconfig.json [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/dotnet.runtimeconfig.json]      [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/dotnet.runtimeconfig.dev.json]
------**

    1 warning found (use docker --debug to expand):
    - FromPlatformFlagConstDisallowed: FROM --platform flag should not use constant value   "linux/amd64" (line 2) Dockerfile-TestAPI:27
    --------------------
    **  25 |     COPY ["XYZ.Test.Data/XYZ.Test.Data.csproj", "XYZ.Test.Data/"]
    26 |     COPY ["XYZ.Forms.Domain/XYZ.Test.Domain.csproj", "XYZ.Test.Domain/"]
    27 | >>> RUN dotnet restore -v d "XYZ.Test.API/XYZ.Test.API.csproj"
    28 |     COPY . .
    29 |     WORKDIR "/src/XYZ.Test.API"
    --------------------**
    ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet restore -v d  XYZ.Test.API/XYZ.Test.API.csproj\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 147`


Unfamiliar with .NET. I tried to repro your problem and it ran without issue unless I moved the container's (!) /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/dotnet.runtimeconfig.json file. Is there an explanation as to why this file wouldn't exist in your container? Something of the form docker run --interactive --tty --rm mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine ash -c "more /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/dotnet.runtimeconfig.json"

Since your goal is Cloud Run, you could try building the container using Cloud Build (and a known good build environment) using gcloud run deploy foo --source=${PWD} --project=... --region=... --no-allow-unauthenticated --max-instances=1 or similar.

DazWilkin - I just checked the .net6 Docker container we have as a point of  reference and they do not have this folder/file structure (/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/dotnet.runtimeconfig.json), I believe Docker is looking at the wrong path during the .Net8 build for some reason. I'm going to take a look at CloudBuild, thanks for your suggestion.

Looking at this again, your Docker Log does not appear to (correctly) correspond to the Dockerfile that you included. In your Dockerfile, you're defining FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine  AS build. This is the container image that I used. This container image contains the path that I referenced. For some reason, when you get to the dotnet restore command, that path is not present (and is expected) and you're getting the error as a result.

@DazWilkin The following changes needed to be made.
ARG BUILDPLATFORM=linux/amd64 FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:8.0-alpine-extra AS base, commented adding icu-libs and tzdata libraries; If you need globalization support for .NET8 API you can use the new extra version of the Alpine runtime-deps image, which includes ICU and Time Zone data libraries, Added: ENV DOTNET_NUGET_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION=false because the restore was unresponsive and commented -p:PublishTrimmed=true \  Rider displayed a msg that .Net8 MS MVC does not support trimming.
